# MultiValueDictKeyError at / 'name'

Tags: python, django, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4wSU.png)

i just want to fetch the data from my website and record it to my django databae

this my views.py code :

```
 def index(request):
        feature1 = Feature.objects.all()
        Appnt = Appointment.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'GET':
          Appnt.name = request.GET['name']
          Appnt.email = request.GET['email']
          Appnt.phone = request.GET['phone']
          Appnt.Adate = request.GET['date']
          Appnt.Dept = request.GET['department']
          Appnt.Doc = request.GET['doctor']
          Appnt.message = request.GET['message']
       contaxt = {
         'feature1' : feature1,
         'Appointment' : Appnt
                 }
      return render(request, 'index.html', contaxt)
```

Comment: It means that the `name` (and likely other) parameters are missing in the querystring.

Comment: how do i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters can be blank (not passed), use `get`:

```py
def index(request):
   feature1 = Feature.objects.all()
   Appnt = Appointment.objects.all()
   if request.method == 'GET':
      Appnt.name = request.GET.get('name')
      Appnt.email = request.GET.get('email')
      Appnt.phone = request.GET.get('phone')
      Appnt.Adate = request.GET.get('date')
      Appnt.Dept = request.GET.get('department')
      Appnt.Doc = request.GET.get('doctor')
      Appnt.message = request.GET.get('message')
   context = {
      'feature1' : feature1,
      'Appointment' : Appnt
   }
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

If the parameters should not be blank, the problem is how the client makes the request.